# Android paging library 3 how to load from room first instead of waiting for remote response using RemoteMediator

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-paging-library

I implemented a recycler view adapter using Android paging library 3 with Room and RemoteMediator, but my problem is that, the list takes a little while to load during initial load. If I removed the RemoteMediator with just data source from Room, the list loaded immediately.
What I want is to load data from Room first, then only fetch from server and insert into database afterwards if reaching end of page. Does anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What version of the library are you using? As of 3.0.0-alpha03, `REFRESH` loads triggered by `RemoteMediator` and `PagingSource` are launched asynchronously so they shouldn't block each other.

If you're encountering this bug on alpha03, please share your setup and file an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=413106&template=1096385

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!
Sorry I think I didn't have my question clear enough, What I mean is that when app first launched, the list will take like maybe 500 milliseconds to load, after that whenever I exit the activity and reenter, the list able to show immediately, does it has anything to do with caching?

Comment: If you are using the PagingSource implementation generated by Room with a RemoteMediator that fetches from network, you are caching loaded items from RemoteMediator into DB via Room. If you are using Paging 3.0.0-alpha03, then you're most likely seeing an empty list before the network call returns because your DB is empty. It's really hard to say without more information! Could you post the code for your setup including your Pager, PagingSource, RemoteMediator implementation as well as your usage with PagingDataAdapter to submit the PagingData?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, due to tight timeline for this project, I have to put it aside for now since it's not really a big issue right now. Maybe I will bring it up again in future, thanks ya!